# Preferred way to have dependable models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How can I handle objects that depend on other objects? Say I have a `PostCollection`, and a `UserCollection`. The `PostModel` have the following attributes: `id, body, timestamp, user_id`. The `UserModel` have `id, firstname, lastname, picture`. Multiple posts may refer to the same user. The `PostView` should have access to both the `PostModel` and the `UserModel`, so that it can display nicely. Obviously a post cannot request the corresponding user before it has been fetched itself. Additionally there may be others who also depend on the `UserCollection`.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You could wait until the `UserCollection` is fetched before showing the `PostView`. Then create a property on the `PostModel` that references the newly-fetched `UserModel`.

Comment: Use deferred....

Comment: I would go for a MVVM approach where you create a `PostViewModel` which is only used for your `PostView`. This new model should handle the logic of first retrieving the `PostModel` and then requesting the `UserModel`. This way your other collections/models keep representing the API while the `PostViewModel` is representing the data you need in your view.